# regex: converting php code from eregi to preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to find the proper regular expression to convert `eregi($1,$2)` to `preg_match("/$1/i",$2)`

i need to consider if there will be functions with () in it, and they may appear more then once.
can anyone please provide the proper regular expression to do so ?

thanks

Comment: I doubt that we can really help much without seeing some examples first.  From what it sounds like, a parser is more suited for this task, but perhaps you have your reasons for wanting to do this with regular expressions.  However, I doubt that it will be a simple drop-in replacement unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use a regular expression to parse code.

You want to use a parser.

Comment: i don't mind using a parser, i just want to find a way to replace one function to another in my code. what kind of parser i can use and how?

Comment: ok.. so php as a tokenizer extension that converts php code to tokens and from that i can convert back to code. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to modify your source code, since `eregi` is [deprecated](https://www.php.net/eregi)? This regex will do the trick:

```
$source= <<<STR
eregi(\$1, \$2);
eregi('hello', 'world');
STR;

$source2= preg_replace("/eregi\(['\"]*([^\'\"),]+)['\"]*,\s*['\"]*([^'\"),]+)['\"]*\)/", 'preg_match("/$1/i", "$2")', $source);

var_dump($source2);
```

Comment: unfortunately this regex doesn't work for the following line of code:
`        if (!eregi('Windows 9', php_uname())) {`